# To take a difference in another data frame based on the 1st data frame for a specific condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sum, pandas-groupby

I have a query on taking a difference from one dataframe to another based on 'Fruits' and 'month' in my data, below is my code-

Data frame 1-

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
k={'Fruits':['Apple','Apple','Apple','Apple'],'month':['201401','201502','201603','201604'],'Quant':[200,400,700,800]}
r=pd.DataFrame(data=k)
```

Data frame 2-

```
s={'Fruits':['Apple','Orange', 'Banana', 'Mango','Apple','Orange', 'Banana', 'Mango'],'month':['201401','201502','201603','201604','201402','201503','201604','201605'],'weight':['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h'],'Quant':[132,178,298,300,121,213,123,30]}
p=pd.DataFrame(data=s)
```

O/P of dataframe1-

[image]

O/P of dataframe2-

[image]

As you can see in the 2nd data frame for Apples in 201401, the quant value sums up to 253.
In the 1st data frame Apple in 201401 is 200.
What I would want to do here, is to remove those rows in 2nd data frame, whose sum is less than 200, so the row with weight 'a' is removed. But when it reaches to 201401 in the 4th index, it remembers the sum (132+121=253), but only removes 53 from 121 computing it to 68.

The desired data frame should look like this-

```
    Fruits  month   weight  Quant
4   Apple   201401   e       68
```

I want to retain the row as weight is a unique identifier here.

Comment: Can you restate your problem in more general terms?  If not, can you explain what the expected output would be for other `month` values?

Comment: @ephsmith basically the 1st dataframe acts here as a reference, for 201401 has a value of 200, the program would now check in 2nd dataframe that if the sum exceeds above 200 for the particular row, it will calculate the difference hence this case was only possible for 201401.
For other years 201502, 201603, 201604, the total value in the datframe 1 was greater than the sum of values in 2nd dataframe, hence we remove those rows.

Comment: To add here, the code will also remove those rows where we begin summing up from the start ie in 201401 the value of quant starts from 132, which is less than 200, hence we remove this row. But when it comes to 121(4th index), the sum for 201401 will be 253, hence we take the difference as 253>200 and we retain the row where the difference was taken.

Comment: the input dataframe you've provided is not the same as the one in the image

Comment: @enke updated the same, thanks for letting me know.

Comment: it still doesn't match (I think the months don't match) because when I do `groupby` I can't get 253.

Comment: @enke good question, basically thats what the program has to do, when you groupby you see 132 and 121, which is 253, that wont sum up as weights are different, which is a unique identifier, so basically the code should understand that a sum is taking place and accordingly remove that particular record, when it goes beyond say 200 in this case